# Rust in Docker with ability to run kotlinc

Tags: docker, kotlin, rust, docker-compose, x11

## Problem 1

I have a Rust GUI application (uses fltk-rs) that runs Kotlin scripts and I'd like to dockerise it. How do I go about loading both compilers and should I have separate containers for each compiler?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest

# Install Kotlinc and X11 packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxtst6 libgtk-3-0 curl unzip && \
    curl -sSL "https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.6.10/kotlin-compiler-1.6.10.zip" -o kotlinc.zip && \
    unzip kotlinc.zip -d /usr/local && \
    rm kotlinc.zip && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables for X11 forwarding
ENV DISPLAY=:0
ENV LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

# Copy the Rust application into the container
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory to the Rust application directory
WORKDIR /app

# Build and run the Rust application
CMD cargo run
```

And here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

And here's my `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "gui-editor"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
fltk = "^1.3"
```

And here's the error message:

```
    Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded paste v1.0.12
  Downloaded crossbeam-channel v0.5.7
  Downloaded ttf-parser v0.18.1
  Downloaded bitflags v1.3.2
  Downloaded cmake v0.1.49
  Downloaded cfg-if v1.0.0
  Downloaded cc v1.0.79
  Downloaded crossbeam-utils v0.8.15
  Downloaded fltk v1.3.34
  Downloaded fltk-sys v1.3.34
   Compiling cc v1.0.79
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.15
   Compiling paste v1.0.12
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling ttf-parser v0.18.1
   Compiling cmake v0.1.49
   Compiling crossbeam-channel v0.5.7
   Compiling fltk-sys v1.3.34
   Compiling fltk v1.3.34
   Compiling gui-editor v0.1.0 (/app)

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1    
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcshVuKw/symbols.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.147kmsloy1i1rvq6.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.15upxipefzjeam3x.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.19pgoumevyjpp34f.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1ajucodluc3gk0o3.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1aoluz56yxhnfarx.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1csfmfqgrcz0mai2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1ebxhz8i4dclsd5h.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1l5ar48ht1fxolt4.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1lc21ylhtlkjslut.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1ly5xjrtv5uzmnl5.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1nkb8wasjk944fly.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1uau3fpq78kcnxyk.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1yawqysq7kx7d2bv.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.20ac0ti8nphm5b82.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.25yrewhx1pxov6bd.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2854p21fyawrfo5t.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2a8kjdckcdkgcmbf.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2au380a1k6pcmdw.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2dj53did2ctlkt5f.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2dvmv4j62mnaum61.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2ege3tm23ppfd8mt.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2gf24ng67uysgg8n.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2jwu1r62ysjtsp2w.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2nb9nxtnxe88575r.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2pv97s53d2tfgjb3.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2vpzf3sowa0xb8pn.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2w5c2tztcainpdft.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2wuogccfsvpcs5q6.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2xifib68kk7esama.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2yq3ha1w72sz8f43.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.2yy7ec4mlpuqnifw.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.30nry2mbteeie6cb.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.30t8tndpjq0f7eup.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.36aq1lr6yyn48eix.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.37mzidnckml8bon3.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3d29cpla3yz0i3il.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3gkvy6rhwrhlyn40.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3j203550oxv6r2es.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3kqjqjvp5re9bilt.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3n8ku7fy1w92vmgx.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3nox2c42yjr1ph8r.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3og6sjeimxos9gcd.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3ostt48vnludv6rj.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3ovstp1q2pro6o1y.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3pfi1i47z082hc46.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3pshgwr509b8p0yv.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3pxvp0i3p0bq8r1d.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3r80aomdbwal84bu.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3sk1d66r1nq8knw2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3t2aydp7b5ptnw51.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3t8lnww05roblt8a.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3v3l2f8rzxn9oyvy.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.3ydbmrp572ydev1e.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4eucyhvpe2r8jmuw.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4jdjeq39t9cp14qx.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4knp0y5rr0np8x1o.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4o1vis6nr38jguhe.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4orcwo4bf6x3rxj6.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4po8jfasye85bbv2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4ukjvvgoznz7l3ti.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.4w73lxl1a40i518.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.512daksd4n9p3g4j.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.52dwa2icyyi5shbe.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.53y7pg1visonbawl.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.54dhkdwwu4fmj6e2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.587a9igh0ds1gy1y.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.58qxkwmd3sjh2d4o.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.59d4lzg9ftsyrscd.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.5apniexn97yqva73.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.5fyv3yekz0w6adt2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.9e211prf62a2xjx.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.e5dwutnjjjes42r.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.eywvqw11e91ebg.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.i6ggipwez3swykz.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.iadu2geaka32su8.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.j1lqz8jf6rkphz5.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.k18bknfiqkixawp.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.n282ikmdjvp6nc0.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.owc3h488i79k591.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.pfsehxd8toqazes.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.y40pgcpulob16gj.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.z3ysrjwv5vs9o3x.rcgu.o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0.1rpmdrbtnojkyzb0.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/app/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/build" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/build/Release" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/lib" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/lib64" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/lib/Release" "-L" "/app/target/debug/build/fltk-sys-e091184a760abd96/out/lib64/Release" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/app/target/debug/deps/libfltk-4419266a67a8f62a.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libttf_parser-e9db07fbcf5dfe1b.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libcrossbeam_channel-1c98a228976f19da.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libcrossbeam_utils-c33aaf21574f0915.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libcfg_if-7c8939aed7ae2b7e.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-e4bdc6ecf4aa2be2.rlib" "/app/target/debug/deps/libfltk_sys-33938cd029c414ab.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-f55ee4dfcef9d6c2.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-3b7b2120c59cf4cf.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-1be4bbab557ba5f9.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-818055ac265188d7.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-c76c474cd6fc2707.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-cef5ed5b7e7bc525.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-92ada7f71df4f807.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-515d5a7096b744bd.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-9988794e1a662dfa.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-b57230631749f36f.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-55f9432d7fd1ddf0.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-67b2e0904cc8c6bf.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-e3574c40ac08e8ec.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-fd674a7ef4c5e3dc.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-4fad884586188abd.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-bc8a4a55f03c7704.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-639fe4992aa3175d.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-e0ad026a086e3293.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-87185c5e58e44fea.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lpthread" "-lX11" "-lXext" "-lXinerama" "-lXcursor" "-lXrender" "-lXfixes" "-lXft" "-lfontconfig" "-lpango-1.0" "-lpangoxft-1.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lcairo" "-lpangocairo-1.0" "-lsupc++" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/app/target/debug/deps/gui_editor-be40e37c553ea5b0" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXcursor       
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXfixes        
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0     
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangoxft-1.0  
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


warning: `gui-editor` (bin "gui-editor") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `gui-editor` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

From the error message I can tell it's a problem with the linking process but I don't know how to address this issue.

## Problem 2

```
FROM rust:1.68.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    # Install packages.
    apt-get install -y \
        libxinerama-dev \
        libxcursor-dev \
        libxfixes-dev \
        libxft-dev \
        libpango1.0-dev \
        libpangoxft-1.0-0 \
        libcairo2-dev \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libxcb-dri3-0 \
        libxtst6 \
        libgtk-3-0 \
        xorg \
        openjdk-11-jdk && \
    # Download kotlinc.zip from GitHub and place it in a directory called kotlinc.zip.
    curl -sSL "https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/download/v1.8.10/kotlin-compiler-1.8.10.zip" -o kotlinc.zip && \
    # Unzip the directory and place it in the /usr/local directory.
    unzip kotlinc.zip -d /usr/local && \
    # Remove the zipped directory.
    rm kotlinc.zip

# Set environment variables for X11 forwarding.
ENV DISPLAY=:0
ENV LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1

# Copy the Rust application into the container.
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory to the Rust application directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Build and run the Rust application.
CMD cargo run
```

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=:0
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    network_mode: host
```

New error message:

```
gui-editor-app-1  | Can't open display: :0
gui-editor-app-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: looks like you need to provide Xinerama, Xcursor, Xfixes, Xft, pango, pangoxft, and pangocairo?

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: Adding these dependencies removed the error message, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although, It is not reproducible from information provided, but looking at log seem installing below package in docker container should solve issue.

```
apt install libxinerama-dev libxinerama1 libxcursor-dev libxcursor1 libxfixes-dev libxfixes3 libxft-dev libxft2 libpango1.0-dev libpango-1.0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
```

Comment: I've updated the Dockerfile and it now doesn't show the same error message, but now I get an error message saying "Can't open display :0". I've updated my question with the new information.